# Drawer Navigator não abre - React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

Estou fazendo um projeto em React Native utilizando o `React Navigation 3.x` e tentando utilizar o `Drawer Navigator`, já utilizei ele no `React Navigation 2.7` e funcionou perfeitamente, só que agora por algum motivo ele não abre, eu tento puxar ele na tela e ele não abre, eu coloquei no método `componentDidMount` da tela que o `Drawer Navigator` está a função `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` e  agora quando a tela é carregada o drawer aparece só que eu também não consigo fechar ele, mas se eu clico em uma das opções do drawer ele seleciona e fecha, é como se as funções de abrir e fechar o drawer deslizando o dedo na tela estivessem desativadas, alguém sabe o por que disso?

Código:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Horarios: {
    name: 'Horarios',
    screen: HorariosQueryComponent
  }

}, { drawerWidth: 250 });

export default createAppContainer(Drawer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o erro, pesquisando mais sobre o `React Navigation 3.x` descobri que eu precisava adicionar um codigo no meu `MainActivity.java`.

O código que precisa colocar esta aqui: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score -2):

Eu tbm acabei de ter o mesmo erro em react-navigation v4 e pelo, no erro diz que tanto a v3 e a v4 devem funcionar com o createAppContainer, entaão, estou a disponibilizar o meu código para vocês analisar

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {} from 'react-native-screens';
import ParImpar from './pages/ParImpar';
import Export_Import from './pages/Componente';
import MegaCena, {Invert} from './pages/ExpImp';


export default createAppContainer(
    createDrawerNavigator({
        MegaCena:{
            screen: () => <MegaCena numbers={3} />,
            NavigatorOptions: {title: "Mega cena"}
        },
        Invert:{
            screen: () => <Invert sentece="Native" />
        },
        Export_Import:{
            screen: () => <Export_Import texto="MAJ" />
        },
        ParImpar:{
            screen: () => <ParImpar number = {3}/>,
            NavigatorOptions: {title: "Par ou Impar"} 
        }
    }, { drawerWidth: 300 })
)
```